# Pressing home button while Progress Dialog was showing throws exception

Tags: android, exception, listview, adapter, progressdialog

I sent a server request and shown user a progress dialog with following properties

```
waitDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        waitDialog.setMessage(getText(R.string.msg_plz_wait));
        waitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        waitDialog.show();
```

Step1: Sent server request

Step2: Shown User a Dialog

Step3: User presses home button while dialog was visible and showing

Step4: data came from server passed to list adapter but could not found resource and throws Resource not found exception that is handled and then ProgressDialog throws following exception.

```
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1432)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-18 12:18:11.050: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15113):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, It has nothing to do with the ProgressDialog, But caused by the listview, this is all I could tell based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not you progress dialog.

It's something you are doing, after your server request is ready.

What does happen, if user doesn't press the home button? Does issue still occur?

Comment: does the issue occur if there is no progress dialog and the user presses home button?

Comment: r u using in you code dismissDialog()? maybe this is the problem. because dialog is using context and if the user presses home button, context of the activity, which called the dialog, will be null. this will cause the null pointer exception

Comment: let me surround it with try catch blocks. I am using dialog.dismiss()

Comment: i'm doing it on another way. i'm saving reference to context in a member. So you can just proof, if activity context is null or not. If it's not you can call dismiss(), otherwise you don't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing `waitDialog.setCancelable(false)`? Does that make a difference?

Comment: No it doesn't make any difference.